# Can't download using Nexus 3 REST API and CURL

Tags: rest, curl, download, nexus, nexus3

I'm trying to download the latest snapshot dependency of a zip on Nexus 3 (version 3.22.1-02) from a command line using curl:

```
curl -u username:password -X GET "https://mynexusserver/service/rest/v1/search/assets/download?sort=version&repository=snapshotsrepo&maven.groupId=mygroup&maven.artefactId=myartefact&maven.extension=zip" -H "accept: application/json" -o myartefact.zip
```

This request is similar to this example: http://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/search-api#SearchAPI-DownloadingtheLatestVersionofanAsset but no result is returned, myartefact.zip is empty.

However with the same URL, my artefact is downloaded from a web browser or with gradle.

With curl the following command line is working fine, returning the list of all snapshot versions of my artefact:

```
curl -u username:password -X GET "https://mynexusserver/service/rest/v1/search/assets?sort=version&repository=snapshotsrepo&maven.groupId=mygroup&maven.artefactId=myartefact&maven.extension=zip" -H "accept: application/json" -o myartefact.zip
```

Downloading the artefact directly is working fine as well with a command line like:

```
curl -u username:password "https://mynexusserver/repository/snapshotsrepo/mygroup/batchfactory/myversion-SNAPSHOT/myartefact-myversion-mytimestamp.zip" -H "accept: application/json" -o myartefact.zip
```

Verbose logs (-v option) show the artefact is found (I get HTTP/1.1 302 Found message) but nothing is downloaded.

Using wget doesn't work any better, I can't even query the list of snapshot version of the artefact.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `curl` does not follow 302 redirections by default, use `-L`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Zeitounator, after adding "-L" the command line works fine. Considering code 302 this feels obvious now...

Nexus documentation should also probably be updated to add the "-L" option.