# How do I search by checksum (SHA1, etc...) with Nexus 3 REST API?

Tags: rest, nexus3

I had a look at the documentation of the API but did not find a listing of all the possible query parameters, and in particular, could not find an appropriate parameter to search by SHA1, or other checksum :

https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/integrations/rest-and-integration-api/search-api

https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/integrations/rest-and-integration-api/assets-api

Previously in Nexus 2 it was possible to do this with 2 endpoints `data_index` and `lucene` :

https://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/lucene/search?sha1=686ef3410bcf4ab8ce7fd0b899e832aaba5facf7
https://nexus.xwiki.org/nexus/service/local/data_index?sha1=686ef3410bcf4ab8ce7fd0b899e832aaba5facf7

I had a look at what endpoint Nexus 3 queries internally, and it's again another endpoint called `extdirect` which uses POST.

I found on some other post that it is already deprecated https://groups.google.com/a/glists.sonatype.com/g/nexus-users/c/8_DyIZrt9mM

Other answers didn't help, in fact I couldn't find 2 answers that agree on the parameter names.

Here it's a strange spelling of `artifact` spelled `artefact` with a 'e'

[Can't download using Nexus 3 REST API and CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61499973/8315843)

```
curl -u username:password -L -X GET "https://mynexusserver/service/rest/v1/search/assets/download?sort=version&repository=snapshotsrepo&maven.groupId=mygroup&maven.artefactId=myartefact&maven.extension=zip" -H "accept: application/json" -o myartefact.zip
```

In this answer, the parameters are again different:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71126636/8315843

```
curl -u token:tokenPassword -L -X GET "https://MY_NEXUS/service/rest/v1/search/assets/download?sort=version&repository=MY-REPO&group=MY_GROUP&name=MY_ARTIFACT_NAME&version=MY_Version&maven.extension=zip" --output My_Artifact.zip
```

So, for artifact, is it `maven.artifactId` or `name` ?
For group, is it `maven.groupId` or `group` ?
How would I get `token:tokenPassword` ? Can't I just use `username:password` ?